# Prisma Query doesn't log using all methods

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm trying to debug what is wrong with a query as it doesn't return any results.

I'm trying the query logger using the following snippet, but no joy

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log: [
        {
            emit: "event",
            level: "query",
        },
    ],
});

prisma.$on("query", async (e) => {
    console.log(`${e.query} ${e.params}`)
});

module.exports = prisma
```

I'm using express, but this should relate to this.

NODE_ENV=development

I have also tried this package: prisma-query-log
but also it doesn't work. What am I missing

This is the query:

```
const query = {
       skip: offset,
       take: limit,
    };
const filteredProperties = prisma.property.findMany(
        query
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually start the query you need to await or call `then` after the query because prisma queries are lazy:

```
const filteredProperties = await prisma.property.findMany(query)
// or like that
prisma.property.findMany(query).then(filteredProperties => ...)
```